# How to make "Marketing Cloud Resubscribe" custom link available on Lightning Record Page

Tags: salesforce-lightning, salesforce-marketing-cloud, page-layout

I have added the "Marketing Cloud Resubscribe" custom link on the page layout in Salesforce, but I can't find it availably on the Lightning Record Page.

Contact Custom Link:

[image: Contact Custom Link]

Contact Page Layout:

[image: Contact Page Layout]

I tried adding the custom link to the page layout, and was expecting it to show on the lightning record page. Also, tried editing in the lightning app builder page to see if it needed to be added from there as well, but could not find it.